Advice on problem solving in mathematics
I am in need of some advice on how to improve my problem solving in mathematics.
I have been taking calculus for a while now, and I have noticed something, I have never been able to actually come up with solutions by myself. Whenever when I do my assignments, when I come into problems that I have no clue or never dealt with before, usually I just try and look up solutions across the internet, because I just literally have zero clue where to start. And it makes me feel really frustrating.
I do programming myself, and when I do programming trying to solve problems I am able to think it through the logic and stuff, and figure it out eventually. But when it comes to math I just couldn't for some reason! I really tried to solve it through my own thinking but I am just not able to... all I can do I just apply formulas and never be able to 'solve' problems.
So how can I improve my problem solving when it comes to math? And how do I start when I come into problems that I have zero clue how to deal with?

Grab a Shaum’s outline and work through every problem, twice. Resist the temptation to look up answers until you’ve wrestled with them. An important skill to develop is patience.

Read How to Solve It by Polya

After you found the answer on the internet you should try to grasp the idea/technique used to solve the problem.In this way you can solve similar questions.

Problems in a calculus course are usually closely related to the course material that has been covered within the past week or so.  So the first step should probably be to look at that material and see how it might be related to this problem.
Are there worked examples that might be related in some way to this problem? If there are such examples, how do they differ from this problem?  How might you change the solution to deal with such differences?
If there are no examples, look at the "theoretical" material.  Is there anything relevant to this example?
For example, maybe there's a theorem that says something like "every X has property Y".  Does your problem involve something that might be an X, or something that might have property Y?  If so, how could that help you with your problem?
Maybe if you gave us an example of the type of problem that gives you trouble, we could have more specific advice.
